# MySQL ALTER TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I would like alter my table so that the table is sorted alphabetically as well as then reset my AUTO_INCREMENT Field (prof_id).

Attached is the database structure. The Foreign Key in 'my_contacts' is still NULL.

I have run an "ALTER TABLE profession ORDER BY profession"

[image]

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no reason to do this.  If you want things in order when you query, then you have to use `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like alter my table so that the table is sorted alphabetically

That's strange and doesn't happen that way. You should rather get the sorted/ordered data while doing a `SELECT` statement using an `ORDER BY` clause like below

```
select * from profession order by profession;
```

Again I would suggest, change you column name different than the table name. In your case, table name and column name both the `profession`.

> then reset my AUTO_INCREMENT Field (prof_id).

Not sure why you would want to reset the PK field; anyways you can do the same using an `ALTER` statement like

```
ALTER TABLE profession AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: I agree that the column names should be different from the table name but unfortunately i was asked to create it as it is. The solution to my problem i created a temporary table then imported the data from profession. Exported the table then imported back into profession(truncated the table).